# Is there a way to use regular if/else in header or better options instead preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
class MyMainClass{
//somecodes

// #define XXX 1

#ifdef XXX
    VClass *x = new Class1();
#else
    VClass *x = new Class2();
#endif

//some other codes
}
```

I have this code in my header file to choose which class i will use for program. I have a globals header file. If i define a var there, can i use it in header without ifdef, define clauses? Like:
globals.h:

```
constexpr bool glb = true;
```

And use it with regular if/else or something to choose between object instantiations?

Comment: I mean it is just a part of it:)

Comment: i corrected my post

Comment: Have a look at class templates, and `if constexpr`.

Comment: `VClass *x = new std::conditional_t<glb, Class1, Class2>();`

Comment: offtopic : consider using std::make_unique<Class1>. The use of manual new/delete is not really recommended (memory leaks when you forget delete) and std::make_unique also shows who owns the pointer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this one liner runs well. do you know there is an version of it for choosing across more than 2 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes; see the code below for an example.

```
#include <cstdlib>

class VClass
{
public:
   VClass() {/* empty */}
};

class Class1 : public VClass
{
public:
   Class1() {/* empty */}
};

class Class2 : public VClass
{
public:
   Class2() {/* empty */}
};

enum {
   VCLASS_TYPE_CLASS1 = 0,
   VCLASS_TYPE_CLASS2,
   // additional types could be added here in the future
   NUM_VCLASS_TYPES
};

constexpr int glb = VCLASS_TYPE_CLASS1;  // set this per your preference

class MyMainClass
{
public:
   MyMainClass() {/* empty */}
   ~MyMainClass() {delete x;}

private:
   VClass * CreateX() const
   {
      switch(glb)
      {
         case VCLASS_TYPE_CLASS1: return new Class1();
         case VCLASS_TYPE_CLASS2: return new Class2();
         default:                 std::abort();  // bad glb setting!?
      }
   }

   VClass * x = CreateX();
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   MyMainClass mmc;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using if/else in header gives me "Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers" error.  std::conditional_t worked without error.

Comment: It seems you're not really asking about what can work "in a header" so much as what can work in a member-variable's declaration line.  The code I posted works in a header file, but it does require that the if-statement be located inside a method-body.

Comment: Hmm now i see. I missed u added it in constructor.

Comment: I've updated my example code to make it closer to what I think you had in mind.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it solves the choosing across more than 2 classes.